Training or finetuning RETRO model with my own dataset using lucidrains RETRO-pytorch
While running the Trainingwrapper script of lucidrain/RETRO-pytorch in Google colab, I get the exception: No embeddings found in folder .tmp/embeddings. The log says there's a file saved in that location and I have checked for a file there and file saves perfectly but still it says not found. I tried to manually create a folder named embeddings in temp folder in colab but didn't solve the problem.
The script is given below:
wrapper = TrainingWrapper(
    retro = retro,                                 # path to retro instance
    knn = 2,                                       # knn (2 in paper was sufficient)
    chunk_size = 64,                               # chunk size (64 in paper)
    documents_path = './text_folder',              # path to folder of text
    glob = '**/*.txt',                             # text glob
    chunks_memmap_path = './train.chunks.dat',     # path to chunks
    seqs_memmap_path = './train.seq.dat',          # path to sequence data
    doc_ids_memmap_path = './train.doc_ids.dat',   # path to document ids per chunk (used for filtering neighbors belonging to same document)
    max_chunks = 1_000_000,                        # maximum cap to chunks
    max_seqs = 100_000,                            # maximum seqs
    knn_extra_neighbors = 100,                     # num extra neighbors to fetch
    max_index_memory_usage = '100m',
    current_memory_available = '1G'
)

the error says embeddings are saved but can't find them:
embedded 7 / 7
saved .tmp/embeddings/00000.npy
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8a66455104f9> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 ).cuda()
     18 
---> 19 wrapper = TrainingWrapper(
     20     retro = retro,                                 # path to retro instance
     21     knn = 2,                                       # knn (2 in paper was sufficient)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/embedding_reader/numpy_reader.py in __init__(self, embeddings_folder)
     75         self.count = self.headers["count"].sum()
     76         if self.count == 0:
---> 77             raise ValueError(f"No embeddings found in folder {embeddings_folder}")
     78         self.nb_files = len(self.headers["count"])
     79         self.dimension = int(self.headers.iloc[0]["dimension"])

ValueError: No embeddings found in folder .tmp/embeddings


Also I have a GPU so I tried to run the scripts locally and it gets following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\RETRO-pytorch\wrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    ).cuda()
      ^^^^^^
  File "D:\RETRO-pytorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 915, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\RETRO-pytorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 779, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "D:\RETRO-pytorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 804, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
                    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\RETRO-pytorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 915, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\RETRO-pytorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 284, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Running both on Google colab GPU environment and loaclly.
